# Does a Banach valued Cauchy series over arbitrary set converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces, absolute-convergence

**Definitions:**
If $f$ is a function from a set $A$ (not necessarily countable) into a Banach space $V$, we say that the series of $f$ over $A$ converges if there exists an element $v \in V$ such that for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists a finite subset $B$ of $A$ such that, for all finite subset $C$ of $A$, if $B$ is contained in $C$, than the distance between the sum over $C$ of $f$ and $v$ is less then $\epsilon$.

If $f$ is a function from a set $A$ into a Banach space $V$, we say that the series of $f$ over $A$ is Cauchy if for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists a finite subset $B$ of $A$ such that, for all finite subsets $C$ and $D$ of $A$, if $B$ is contained in $C$ and $D$, then we have that the distance between the sum over $C$ of $f$ and the sum over $D$ of $f$ is less then $\epsilon$.

**Question:** is it true that a Cauchy series is convergent? Proof? Counterexamples?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what **your thoughts** on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: Banach spaces are, by definition, complete.  What is your definition of a "complete" space?

Comment: i tried to answer this question showing that if the series of f is Cauchy, than f has at most countable support, then to arrange the support of f into a sequence, showing that this series is Cauchy and than that converge, but now i find problems in showing that the series of f converge to this series because it seems that i need something like absolute convergence...

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: yes, but the definition of what is a Cauchy series over an arbitrary set differs from what is a Cauchy series

Comment: Can you show that the sequence of partial sums of a Cauchy series forms a Cauchy sequence?

Comment: Oh, I see, I misunderstood the question